# Quelle est la signification de « J’te replace pas »?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

J'te replace pas , mais j't'ai déjà vu . C'est quoi ton p'tit nom déjà ? LAMY Lamy . MONONC Pis tu te trouves à être ... ? LAMY L'amie de Lui . MONONC Oui oui oui . On s'est déjà vus , hein ? LAMY Oui . Une couple de fois chez Lui .

Quelle serait une autre façon d’exprimer cette idée en français standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ici, *replacer* veut dire [*reconnaître*](https://www.theatre-contemporain.net/textes/Dehors-Gilles-Poulin-Denis/contenus-pedagogiques/idcontent/88302). La phrase signifie donc  ***Je ne te reconnais pas***, ou dans le cas de cet échange, plutôt ***je n'arrive pas à mettre un nom sur ton visage***.

Dans un dialogue, soit ***J'te reconnais pas***, soit ***Je t'reconnais pas***.

On utilise aussi parfois le verbe *remettre*:  ***J'arrive pas à te remettre***.